# .htaccess deny access to just PHP files

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a module directory in my project and I want to prevent access to PHP files inside it.
Besides I have some css and js files in that directory that should be parsed. I used this code in .htaccess

```
deny from all
```

But it made my css and js files not accessible too. How can I prevent access to just PHP files, but not css and js files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked @xbonez code and it gives me the same error.

I'm using this code (tested):

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .+ - [F,L]
```

Remember to set `Options -Indexes` so that your folders are not browseable.

**Edit:**

**Notes:**
* this code must be put into an `.htaccess` file and place it inside your desired directory
* `%{REQUEST_URI}` = the relative url of what you have requested. Example: `directory/style.css`
* `!\.(css|js)$` = every file that doesn't end with css or js
* `.+ - [F,L]` = forbid the requested url/file

Comment: Thank you @machineaddict, I solved it by removing the star. the code should be : <FilesMatch "\.(css|js)$">

Answer (score 0):

After the `deny for all`, you can allow access to `css` and `js` files with this directive

```
<FilesMatch "*\.(css|js)$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Your final `htaccess` should look somewhat like this:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all

<FilesMatch "*\.(css|js)$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Thank you xbonez, I used your code, but it still doesn't parse js and css files. Now in "view srouce" mode when I click on js and css files it gives me "Server Error!" error 500